# How can a django project detect if the system has django installed?

Tags: python, django

I've built a small project on my system.
After building the project, I put it on a USB drive, and copied to another system.
When I run the project, how can it detect if django is installed in the system or if the system has all of the the requirements for the project?

For example, I made a blog example project on a laptop, then copied that project(blog) onto a USB drive and then I copied that project(blog) to my own system. After copying, I tried to run the project. If django is installed then the project runs successfully. But when django is not installed it gives an error in the terminal.

How can the program detect if the required (Django/Python) is installed or not?

Comment: It won't, you need to install and configure Django again.

Comment: You should read this http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/requirements.html#sharing-your-package-list

Comment: Yes Program detects if the required module is installed or not.That's why we get ImportError

Answer (score 1):

Simply the module won't be found when you try to run your project.

You can run 'python' in your command line and try to 'import django' if it returns an error then django isn't found it means that django isn't installed on the current machine.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ans, But It is the command to know myself that django is installed or not and this is <code> pip freeze </code> other way to know that django is installed or not. I am asking that how project  knows that django is installed or not. like in java enviornment variable.

Answer (score 1):

When you will try to run your Django project you will get ImportError and i think it is the detection that django is installed or not.

```
ImportError: No module named django
```

Into your project you can write a new management command to check that in system django is installed or not.
and you can run like .

```
python manage.py is_django_installed
```

even you can customize your runserver/migrate/syncdb management command to check that django is installed or not .